# como hacer en applab un acumulador

Tags: javascript

Quiero en la plataforma code.org (applab) crear un acumulador de botellas. Cuando el usuario coloque un número me salga el número en un text area. Pero luego si vuelvo al home y vuelvo a colocar otro número, me salga la sumatoria de los números en ese mismo text area.

Gracias por la ayuda. Espero haberme explicado

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.